# Telegram:PHP: I want to send bulletted list as a telegram message

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

PHP code for sending code as telegram message is as follows,

```
<?php
$a=1000;  
$b=1200;  
$c=1400;  
$d="<ol align='left'> <font color=red size='4pt'> Salary statement for the Current month</font><br><li> <font color=blue>Salary of Mr. A is : $a$</font>  </li><li> <font color=blue>Salary of Mr. B is : $b$</font></li><br><li> <font color=blue>Salary of Mr. C is : $c$</font></li></ol>"; 

file_get_contents($GLOBALS[site]."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$d);
?>
```

The output In telegram chat window should be like

```
Salary statement for the Current month
Salary of Mr. A is : 1000$
Salary of Mr. B is : 1200$
Salary of Mr. C is : 1400$
```

What I am getting is,

all the html text as it is with just variables replaced with their values.

Guys I want to send bulletted list of some variables along with text to telegram chat. How it is doable?

Comment: Telegram API doesn't support any markup-text for sending messages.It supports only strings (with UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: ok bro, can I send telegram any of telegram smilies in within text msg? 

for ex: Cick on icon :paperclip: below (to show paperclip smiley of telegram)

Answer (score 1):

At the current time of writing only **bold**, *italic*, `code` and fence code blocs are supported by clients.